# Master Detail App with JSON gives uncaught exception __NSCFDictionary objectAtIndexedSubscript

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, xcode4, nsdictionary

I want to fill a master-detail app with JSON data (which is already validated), and am getting error "uncaught exception __NSCFDictionary objectAtIndexedSubscript". Thanks a lot.

The JSON file:

```
{
    "Name": [
    "Entry 1 (Comment1) (Comment1b)",
    "Entry 2 (Comment2) ",
    "Entry 3 (Comment3) ",
    "Entry 4 (Comment4) (Comment4b)"
     ],
"URLs": [
    "http://www.myurl.com/%20(Comment1)%20(Comment1b)",
    "http://www.myurl.com/%20(Comment2)%20(Comment2b)",
    "http://www.myurl.com/%20(Comment3)%20(Comment3b)",
    "http://www.myurl.com/%20(Comment4)%20(Comment4b)"
    ]
}
```

This is how I load the JSON file:

```
@interface MasterViewController () {
    NSArray *_objects;
}
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl.com/Data.json"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    _objects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:NULL];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     return _objects.count;
}
```

This is how I am parsing it:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"_objects contains: %@", _objects);

    // # This following line creates the error:
    NSDictionary *object = _objects [indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"object contains: %@", object);
    cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey: @"Name"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [object objectForKey: @"URLs"];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got you access of the JSON dictionary around the wrong way. The top level objects are dictionaries, but you are treating them as arrays and trying to load by the indexPath.row.

Something like this should work instead:

```
cell.textLabel.text = _objects[@"Name"][indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = _objects[@"URLs"][indexPath.row];
```

Broken out, it looks like this:

```
NSArray *nameArray = _objects[@"Name"];
NSArray *urlArray = _objects[@"URLs"];
cell.textLabel.text = nameArray[indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = urlArray[indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @danielbeard but now I'm getting a compiler warning on the the two lines: "Expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type 'NSArray *'

Comment: Change _objects to be an NSDictionary type

Comment: Thanks @danielbeard, but this now gives me the error in the lines of "tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath" and "prepareForSegue": "Expected method to read array element not found on object of type 'NSDictionary *'"

Comment: You have to also change those respective methods so they are using something similar to the above code (if you are trying to read something from `_objects`.